# Where is the file path of IFormFile?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

When I receive a file from C# to iformfile, how do I know the file path of that file?
If I don't know, how do I set the path?

```
public async Task<JObject> files(IFormFile files){
string filePath = "";
var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filePath)
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-3.1), some instructions on `IFormFile` are introduced:

> Files uploaded using the IFormFile technique are buffered in memory or on disk on the server before processing. Inside the action method, the IFormFile contents are accessible as a Stream.

So for `IFormFile`, you need to save it locally before using the local path.

For example:

```cs
// Uses Path.GetTempFileName to return a full path for a file, including the file name.
var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();

using (var stream = System.IO.File.Create(filePath))
{
    // The formFile is the method parameter which type is IFormFile
    // Saves the files to the local file system using a file name generated by the app.
    await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
}
```

After this, you can get the local file path, namely `filePath`.

Comment: In the case of a large file, isn't it taking a lot of time to get the file path after saving it locally?

Comment: Hello, If you mean to get the file's local path after saving it, it doesn't take a lot of time. In the entire process of reading `IFormFile` and saving it locally, the time-consuming step is the `IFormFile.CopyToAsync()` method. In fact, as an example, I used a temporary file path. You can save to the specified file path, and then read the local file through the path.